# How move window control icons to the right?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I want move control icons(minimize,maximize,close) to the right side of window. On Ubuntu 12.04 it done by command

```
gconftool-2 -s -t string /apps/metacity/general/button_layout ":minimize,maximize,close"
```

But on Ubuntu 14.04 this command not works...

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Ubuntu use gsettings instead of gconftool-2.  This command worked for me:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ':maximize,minimize,close'
```